# How to assign a pointer a 2D square array of unknown size?Whats wrong in the following function?

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc, double-pointer

Here is the code I tried,Segmentation fault was the result..

```
void allocate(int ** universe,int n)              // to assign pointer "a"  a nXn matrix 
{

   universe=(int **) calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
   int l;
   for(l=0;l<n;l++)
   universe[l]=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
   int u;
   for(l=0;l<n;l++)
   for(u=0;u<n;u++)      //making all entries 00
   universe[l][u]=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whats wrong in the following function?

Since arguments are passed by value, your function works on a copy of the passed-in pointer, and doesn't modify the pointer in the caller, that remains uninitialised (or still points where it pointed before), and you can't access the allocated memory from the caller, and trying to access it via `universe[i][j]` is likely to cause a segmentation fault. As a further consequence, when `allocate()` returns, you have lost the only pointers to the allocated memory and that's a leak.

The correct way to do it is to

- return the pointer,

  ```
  int ** allocate(int n)
  {
      int **universe = calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
      if (!universe) {
           fputs(stderr, "Allocation of universe failed.");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      int l;
      for(l = 0; l < n; l++) {
          universe[l] = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
          if (!universe[l]) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate row %d.\n", l);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
      }
      return universe;
  }
  ```

  and call that like `int **universe = allocate(124);`, or
- pass in the address of the pointer you want to allocate memory to,

  ```
  void allocate(int *** universe_addr,int n)        // to assign pointer "a"  a nXn matrix 
  {
      int ** universe = calloc(n,sizeof(int *));
      if (!universe) {
          /* repair or exit */
      }
      int l;
      for(l = 0; l < n; l++) {
          universe[l]=(int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
          if (!universe[l]) {
              /* repair or exit */
          }
      }
      /* Now set the pointer in the caller */
      *universe_addr = universe;
  }
  ```

  and call it like `allocate(&universe, 123);`.

Note: I have removed the initialisation loop, since `calloc` already zeros the allocated memory, hence it is unnecessary to set it to 0 again.

Comment: :Thanks.It worked.But is'nt in case of pointers the actual and formal parameters the same(unlike the copy thing you mentioned)E.g the swapping call i.e (&a,&b) works but not the (a,b)call.And in regard to the above mentioned allocate function if I have to call the function successively ,with different values,Do I  need some kind of freeing routine in between?If yes,would free(universe) work or do I need to free each of the "universe[i]'s"?And finally can the freeing be done via a function(although I guess not by your explanation:copy creation)?

Comment: @Parikshit All arguments are passed by value. So if you pass a pointer, you pass a copy of the pointer. That points to the same address of course, so you can modify the pointed-to memory, but you can't modify where the pointer in the caller points. Hence if you want to allocate memory for a pointer, you must return a pointer to the allocated memory, or pass the address of the pointer (in C++, you can pass arguments by reference, that would be `void allocate(int**& universe, int n)`). Each `malloc` needs a corresponding `free`, so you'd need to free `universe[i]` before freeing `universe`.

Comment: Would a call like void free(int**& universe,int n) free up the entire universe?